# Monitoring EclipseLink JPA progress

Tags: java, logging, jpa, eclipselink, monitoring

I'm back at my first EclipseLink JPA project and noticed some issues regarding the performance. Here's the situation:

The application runs with a local Apache Derby DB. During the creation of the EntityManager the console logs a few infos and warnings, which takes a few seconds but is fine so far. However, if I package the whole code into an executable jar and run it outside Eclipse, the whole process takes a lot more time.

Now while it would be wise to find the reason for this issues in the first place, I at least wanted to add a ProgressBar in order keep rough track of the progress.

I looked up the EclipseLink wiki and found out that it already features a PerformanceMonitor and some logging utilities. I am now stuck at the seemingly simple task of putting 1 and 1 together.

How can I hook up my ProgressBar with EclipseLink? Or another approach: How can I log ongoing activities of EclipseLink in the first place?

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You can use some logging api (log4j) in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable the eclipselink logging by adding this in your persistent unit's properties in the persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="DEBUG"/>
```

to enable a most detailed logging, or even 'ALL' instead of 'DEBUG' if not enough. But remove it when going to production or that line itself will make it slower.

Two common things that could make eclipse link slower are:

having this in in the persistence.xml when not needed:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
```

and NOT having this (if you declare de classes in the persistence.xml file. Set it to false if you do not!!):

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

as of the progress bar, I would say it will be very hard, and not precise since even eclipselink don't know the whole amount of classes it will process in he beginning, so I don't think it's worth the effort, but good luck if you find out a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Lando. That actually helped me understanding a bit more of what I am seeing here. It also helped me figuring out, why the latest project increment didn't work anymore, somebody set the ddl-generation value to 'drop-and-create-tables' -_-

If by any chance you would also know how I can divert the EL logging output to a SWT label or text widget (trying this instead of ProgressBar), please let me know. Looking into this now.

Comment: I thought eclipselink.logging.level uses jul e.g. ALL FINE etc

Answer (score 3):

Here is the steps to produce a log file for an SE project (non-application server one) which has EclipseLink JPA:

1. Open the file "persistence.xml" and assign the following properties:

   property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="JavaLogger"

   property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"
2. Given that Eclipselink JavaLogger is in fact a java.util.logging one, refer to your JDK folder to locate the file logging.properties which is to be modified as follows:

> handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
>
> # Default global logging level.
>
> .level= FINEST
>
> # default file output is in user's home directory
>
> # java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
>
> # but I prefer to hard wire it as follows:
>
> java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = C\:/SamLogFile.log
>
> java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINER
>
> java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
>
> # I personally don't care about the stdout logging, so I turn it off.
>
> java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = OFF
>
> java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
>
> java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%4$s: %5$s [%1$tc]%n

Now you can place some logging within your class by importing:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

And calling:

```
public void yourMethod() { 

Logger.getLogger( YourClassName.class.getName() ).log( Level.INFO, "I am logging well......!" ); }
```

Now you are set. Run/test your project and enjoy reading your log!

Answer (score 3):

You can also take your logging code into a best practice by adding the 2 files slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar and the file slf4j-jdk14-1.7.1.jar to your classpath. These 2 files are to be downloaded from http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Add to your class the imports:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Then add to your method this line:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mysafeperson.class.getName()).info("I am logging using the slf4j api");
```

This practice is making your code using the slf4j api instead of the java.util.logging (JUL) api. Thus your code is decoupled from JUL and ready for any logging framework to be bound as an slf4j implementation (choices are logback - log4j - or [refer to this link.](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#binding))

The idea I am promoting here is based upon the documentation in http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html. So:

- The file: slf4j-api-1.7.1 is your new api facade.
- The file: slf4j-jdk14-1.7.1 makes a bridge from the existing logging implementation which is java.util.logging (JUL) and your application code calling the slf4j api.

#### Two tips remain:

1. Be aware that the available defined levels in JUL are:

   - SEVERE (highest value)
   - WARNING
   - INFO
   - CONFIG
   - FINE
   - FINER
   - FINEST (lowest value)

   Thus don’t use the levels (Error – TRACE – DEBUG) of the slf4j api, they will not trigger any logging level. INFO and WARN are OK to use
2. As for EclipseLink, be aware that you are still tied to using the JUL configuration file logging.properties